# Qt6 Java Android Service doesn't get started

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, service

I am making a mobile app with Qt 6.2 and Java and I want to follow the user location from the mobile client as a background process. Unfortunately it seems the android background service doesn't get started at all? I suspect that my problem is coming from either the Java or the AndroidManifest files and not the C++ Qt6 one.

Here are my files

android/src/org/qtporject/QtAndroidService.java

```java
package org.qtproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtService;

public class QtAndroidService extends QtService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("TEST", "I got created!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("TEST", "I just got here");

        int ret = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


        return ret;
    }

    public static void startQtAndroidService(Context context) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, QtAndroidService.class));

        Log.d("TEST", "Android Service Start");
    }
}
```

android/AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.qtproject.test1"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="test1"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">
        <activity
            android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
            android:label="test1"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="test1" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.arguments"
                android:value="" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.extract_android_style"
                android:value="minimal" />

        </activity>
        <service android:name=".QtAndroidService" android:enabled="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="service" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true" />
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The only log that gets printed from here is "Android Service Start".

onStartCommand doesn't get called, even though it should get called after starting the service in startQtAndroidService. The onCreate function seems to not be called as well since "I got created!!" doesn't print out in the debug console.

Here's is the main.cpp file that calls the startQtAndroidService function ( again I suppose the problem is not a C++ Qt6 one )

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QJniObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (QCoreApplication::arguments().count() > 1)
    {
        qDebug() << "I am the service";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "I am the application";
    }

    QJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>(
        "org/qtproject/QtAndroidService",
        "startQtAndroidService",
        "(Landroid/content/Context;)V",
        QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());

    return app.exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets Core REQUIRED)
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
)

if(ANDROID)
set(ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION 30)
    qt_add_executable(test1
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )

    target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core Qt6::CorePrivate)

    set_property(TARGET test1 APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)

    qt_finalize_executable(test1)


endif()
```

I have followed the [official Qt6 documentation for android services](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/android-services.html) and I suppose that I haven't missed anything. As far as I understand the main.cpp should call startQtAndroidService then startQtAndroidService to call the onStartCommand function and after that my main.cpp file should get called again ( first time for the main thread and second for the android service ), but onStartCommand doesn't get called and my main.cpp gets called only once and prints "I am the application" with no "I am the service" log. I had also put log in the beggining of the main outside the if, but it gets printed once, so I am confident the main function gets called only once.

Could someone please help me out here ? What could I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Check you're using `QtAndroid::androidActivity()` in your `main.cpp` correctly.

```
    QAndroidJniObject service = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField(
                "org/qtproject/QtAndroidService", "INSTANCE",
                "Lorg/qtproject/QtAndroidService;");
            if (service.isValid()) {
                QAndroidJniObject context = QtAndroid::androidActivity().object();
                service.callMethod<void>("startQtAndroidService", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", context.object<jobject>());
            }
```

And in your `QtAndroidService.java` you have a static `INSTANCE` field.

```
package org.qtproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtService;

public class QtAndroidService extends QtService {

    public static QtAndroidService INSTANCE;
    //rest of your code
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer !

I managed to fix it, but I have no idea how. One of the things that  I have changed was rewriting this:
```
        <service android:name=".QtAndroidService" android:enabled="true">
```

as
```
        <service android:process=":qt_service" android:name=".QtAndroidService" android:enabled="true">
```

Comment: @ИвелинИванов thats great!! Im happy you've managed to fixed it